# SMS Based Application How To

Tags: java, sms

I would like to develop an application which users interact with on an sms platform. Its more of an experiment to learn something new. Any pointers on technology to study and things to look at as pre-requisites before diving in? Thanks

Comment: Which SMS platform? Do you have a hardware device you're going to use, or are you going to use an online provider who'll make callbacks to your app, or something else?

Comment: I have never developed in this platform. Am coming from a php, c# background. I just want to have a system that users can send an sms to and get some kind of response from the system. I think that would fall under an online provider with results sent back to users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you'll need a device that can act as a [wireless modem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gsm_modem#Mobile_modems_and_routers) to provide you with a connection for the gateway. If your cellphone supports [tethering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering) and you have an SMS plan, it would be pretty easy to use that. Otherwise you'll need to get a modem and a plan to go with it. I'm not sure how close to the metal you want to get, but you can then use [SMSLib](http://smslib.org/) to listen on the device and wait for incoming messages. With this setup you can both send and receive messages. It is also possible to use something like [Minicom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicom) to send commands directly to the modem for experimenting.

As another approach, you could also use a vendor such as [Clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com/products/gateway.php) as an API for interacting with an SMS gateway. They seem to be able to handle both sending and receiving SMS on behalf of their clients.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a very detailed desc on what needs to be done. Thing is, I want to code the backend for some very 'interesting' data computations and such like things. It will be more than just a messaging service but a system that 'subscribers' can user to automate a wide variety of things, from bookings to automated alerts based on subscription. What programming language is best suited for this? Any manuals?

Comment: I'm not sure that any particular programming language is better suited for this than others. I did just find this rather detailed site that is practically a manual http://www.developershome.com/sms/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with something like Twilio (where I work). Here is a howto for sending/receiving in PHP using just HTTP POST requests: http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/sms/